# flutter: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]

Tags: flutter, dio

I created a login form which fetched the credentials from api and is perfectly working. i have two type of users employee and manager. so there are two dashboard. i store their type in database with name Type, when i am getting response of login api, and get the Type value and store it in type varibale and checking if it equal to Employee the will redirect to employee dashboard else manager dashboard.

It was working fine too, i test it 2 to 3 times, but when i run again my app and login as employee it redirect me to employee dashboard but when i try to login as manager it sending me this dio 400 error.

i did debugging too, i am getting values too in body parameters and on data too, but after that it prints 400 error.

when i run login api on postman and passing manager credentials it working perfectly their too.

here is my login funtion

```
Future login() async {

    Dio dio=new Dio();
    var data={
      'username': user.username,
      'password': user.password,
      'date':formattedDate

      

    };
    await dio
    .post(localhostUrlLogin,data: json.encode(data)) // it prints error after this line
      .then((onResponse) async {
        SharedPreferences myPrefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        
        print(onResponse.data);
        print(onResponse.statusCode);
        
        String type=onResponse.data['User']['Type'];
        print(type);

        if(type=='Employee')
        {
          Navigator.push(
          context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Employee()));
        }
        else if(type=='Manager'){
          Navigator.push(
          context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Manager()));
        }
     
        
       
        myPrefs.setString('name',name );
        myPrefs.setString('email', email);
        myPrefs.setString('designation', designation);
        myPrefs.setString('accesstoken', token);
        myPrefs.setBool('timeinStatus', timeinstatus);
        myPrefs.setString('DOB', dob);
        
      }).catchError((onerror){
        print("error "+onerror.toString());
        showAlertDialog(context);
    });
  }
```

kindly please help, how to fix this.

Comment: In short, you're saying you get the correct data but the statusCode of the response is 400?

Comment: yep, you can say that, i am getting correct data but it send 400 error, and this is only happens when i login as manager

Comment: That could mean the error is on the Server-Side, you should check why the server has sent a 400 response code. Some examples of why 400 occur at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Comment: OMG! when i enter the username i got the name on my keyboard (auto word) and click that, and then entered password, and hit the login button, then it is sending me 400 error, but when i write full username like not selecting the name from auto word it is redirecting me to dashboard

Comment: what kinda thing is this? i did same(selecting auto word) when login as employee, it was working fine.

Comment: Check the exact values of what is being sent to the server.